# DialogFragment dismissed on orientation change

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library, android-dialogfragment, orientation-changes

I have a retained fragment in which I show a dialog fragment. The problem is the dialog get dismissed on orientation change.

*** Please note that the problem I am having is not that the dialog fragment itself has `setRetainInstance(true)`, but the root fragment in which I am showing the dialog ***

Setting it to `setRetainInstance(false)` in the root fragment fixes the issue, but it needs to be retained in my application.

*** What I observed so far is that as long as the `FragmentManager` contains a retained fragment, the dialogs get dismissed on orientation change! Why is that?! ***

I tried the popular workarounds suggested [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17423) and they didn't help.

I am trying to solve this issue for about a year now with no luck.

Comment: A year fulltime? In any case, a minimal example of your relevant code would be helpful.

Comment: I will try to make a test case project and post up the code.

Comment: That would be perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found out what was the root of the problem.
It appeared to be that I was messing around with how the `activity` retain `FragmentManager` and then restore the state of the fragments when activity was recreated.

I made a project that the `Fragment` was static and built in the `activity` layout using `<Fragment>` tag. And the issue was gone.

Since I was using dynamic fragments in my application and static fragments were just fine I suspected that I wasn't replacing the fragments in a right manner in the `onCreate` method of my `activity`.

Corrected that and this issue is fixed.